# Streaming data to a specific BigQuery Time Partition

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to know if there is any way to stream data to a specific time partition of a BigQuery table. The documentation says that you must use table decorators:

> **Loading data using partition decorators**
>
> Partition decorators enable you to load data into a specific
>   partition. To adjust for timezones, use a partition decorator to load
>   data into a partition based on your preferred timezone. For example,
>   if you are on Pacific Standard Time (PST), load all data generated on
>   May 1, 2016 PST into the partition for that date by using the
>   corresponding partition decorator:
>
> `[TABLE_NAME]$20160501`

Source: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#dealing_with_timezone_issues

And:

> **Restating data in a partition**
>
> To update data in a specific partition, append a partition decorator
>   to the name of the partitioned table when loading data into the table.
>   A partition decorator represents a specific date and takes the form:
>
> `$YYYYMMDD`

Source: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables#creating_a_partitioned_table

But if I try to use them when streaming data i got the following error: Table decorators cannot be used with streaming insert.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry for the inconvenience. We are considering providing support for this in the near future. Please stay tuned for more updates.

Possible workarounds that might work in many cases:

1. If you have most of the data available(which is sometimes the case when restating data for an old partition), you can use a load job with the partition as the destination.
2. Another option is to stream to a temporary table and after the data has been flushed from the streaming buffer, use bq cp

Comment: Hi Pavan, thanks for your answer. If I should use the second option and have data from many days, which is the best approach?

1) Stream data to a different table for each day and then copy to the final partitioned table using decorators.
2) Stream data to a unique table and then query the results for each day based on a field and copy them to the final partitioned table using decorators.
3) Other

Thanks in advance

Comment: Quick question: is there a reason you can't stream directly to the table (not a specific partition) and let bigquery infer the partition timestamp. We understand there are cases where this may not be convenient but want to make sure that is indeed the case here.

Comment: For example, one of my users add a new project and want to import their last 30 days data from an external API. I want to stream that data to their correspondent time partitions so then i can query the data of the selected time period in my dashboard. It would be great if we could select one of the fields of the table as the 'partition reference' for infering the partition timestamp. I think it can't be done now. Thanks again Pavan.

Comment: If the number of tables you are going to create every day for this purpose is going to be non-trivial (order of 1000s), I'd suggest doing (2) from your comment. If it is going to be small, I'd suggest doing (1). 

In any case, we are trying to provide streaming to a table partition as soon as we can (order of few weeks) -- I am not sure if that changes your plan of action for the time being.

Comment: We are going to use (1) until we can change to stream to partitions directly. Thanks in advance Pavan!

Comment: How can we get notified when this feature becomes available? I am also interested in it, but for now i stream into a table with date template sufix.

Comment: I will provide an update here once it is available. We are actively working on the feature and hope to provide it soon

Comment: Any news on the feature? Looking forward to it - would like to migrate a couple of prod workflows...

Comment: This should be working now. Please let us know if you see any issues.

Answer (score 1):

This feature was recently released and you can now stream directly into a decorated date partition within the last 30 days historically and 5 days into the future.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery